# Object not rotating properly in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I can't really explane whats going on so here is the video:
[I can't explain this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjDb.gif)

Something went wrong with the rotation axis? I don't know what cause it. I don't know how to fix it.
Its like someone messed something with the axis? I even don't know how to do that...
Please help me!

Comment: Looks fine to me, question unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, it's because you modify the value in Transform, in fact, the changed localPosition and localRotation are relative coordinate values; when this parameter is changed, it is relative to the parent node.

The objects we see in Scene are Position and Rotation, which are the values ​​in world coordinates, which are the relative coordinates plus the parent node's value in world coordinates.

So all you need to do is reset the Transform of the GameObject's parent node to the initial value. [image]

then the modification of the relative coordinates will be consistent with the world coordinates.